# QGIS Plugin "Area Weighted Average" 0 is not in range

Tags: qgis, area

I'm a beginner in QGIS and I'm trying to calculate the population density. I have two layers, one layer with population attributes and one grid layer where my population data should be weighted and inserted. The problem is now that I have grid cells where no population data can be inserted because there is no population. So if I try to use the "Area Weighted Average" Plugin, it doesn't work -> 0 is not in range ?
Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

[image: Example of my grid and 3 of 5 empty cells marked red]
[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you checked with the plugin provider and their FAQ?

Comment: Could you share the whole error message from "Log Messages Panel  > Python error"

Comment: @Erik Yes and I wrote the author of the Plugin an Email but I didnt get a response.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz
There you go.